# XAMPP Multiple Virtual Host

Tags: ubuntu, xampp

Folks,
I have setup virtual host in my VPS on Ubuntu using XAMPP as per below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                                                                             
    ServerAdmin aaa@gmail.com                                                                                                                      
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/abc/public"                                                                                                           
    ServerName domain1.com                                                                                                                                   
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com                                                                                                                          
    ErrorLog "logs/domain1_error_log"                                                                                                                         
    CustomLog "logs/domain1-access_log" common                                                                                                                
</VirtualHost>                                                                                                                                                 

<VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                                                                             
    ServerAdmin aaa@gmail.com                                                                                                                      
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/xyz/public"                                                                                                                
    ServerName domain2.com                                                                                                                                       
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com                                                                                                                                 
    ErrorLog "logs/domain2_error_log"                                                                                                                            
    CustomLog "logs/domain2-access_log" common                                                                                                                   
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try opening domain1.com on browser it works fine, but when I try opening domain2.com it still going to same location of domain1 and loads the index page of domain1.

In my hosts file, I only have my public VPS ip listed against the server name.I did even try adding domain1.com and domain2.com to hosts file with my public ip.

Can someone please help.

Comment: Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself. There were unwanted spaces in vhost file as I copied from notepad to shell. Upon deleting the spaces, the redirect worked fine.